# Example of using PDF library - libharu on Android?

Tags: android, pdf, android-ndk, pdf-viewer, pdfview

Is there an example on using libHaru to view PDF documents? I am newer to NDK development. I do not know how to use this native library. Can anyone suggest an example to me?

Please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no example, because libHaru does not support reading PDF documents.

From the official website:

> At this moment libHaru does not support reading and editing existing PDF files and it's unlikely this support will ever appear.